# Stop purchase cancellation emails from Google Checkout

Tags: android, google-play, android-pay

I know this have been discussed before, but I can't really find any path to solve this issue so far. More after the new Checkuout/Wallet integration, path changed.

I'm dealing with toons of daily emails from Google each time a customer cancel an App. It's kinda spam...

Where can I find the magic checkbox to stop sending these emails?

Thanks!

Google cancelled a recent purchase from your store.

Reason: Customer request to cancel

Please do not process or ship this order. Below is the summary of the transaction.

Comment: I think you may be asking this in the wrong place.

Comment: But this should help http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/27844/google-checkout-stop-emailing-canceled-order-notices/

Comment: that's outdated, google checkout doesn't exist anymore

Comment: Jade, I already found that link on my research... and as Andy said, it's outdated, it's not that way anymore...

Comment: -1 This is a support issue, not a programming question. [SO is for programming questions only](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 2):

- Log into the Android Market, click on use new design.
- Go to reports on the left.
- Click on "Visit your merchant account for more details"
- Click on Settings
- Click on Preferences
- Uncheck "Email me each time I receive an order, cancellation or other transaction"

Comment: This the deal: 1. I log in into my Wallet account. 2. In general if you mean this: "Notifications"
"Send me Google Wallet special offers, invitations to provide product feedback, and newsletters" It's already unchecked, in fact it never was... I have other options too: Transactions,
Payment methods,
Reviews,
Subscriptions,
Devices, not of them is about this matter...

Comment: In the settings, there is no such thing as "Preferences" to click.